# Can I use netcat to run PHP CLI w/ arguments?

Tags: bash, php, netcat

I'm trying to create a debug listener that listens on a port for a data string and forwards it to a php script as an argument. How can I specify that the input to the port should be used as an argument?

For example: The remote device send a string with comma separated values `value1,value2,value3` and I'd like to run the command `php file.php value1,value2,value3` and have the values used in  `$_SERVER["argv"][1]`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?  Every line sent will run a separate invocation of the PHP script.  Note that netcat will quit once the connection is closed; some versions have a flag that tells it to go back to listening.  Or you could wrap the whole thing in a while loop, or you could look into inetd or xinetd instead of netcat, though those might be a bit heavyweight.

```
nc -l myport | while read line ; do php file.php "$line" ; done
```

Comment: This is just what I needed! I added the -k switch to accept multiple connections and it's good enough for now. Maybe later I'll tinker with inetd and replace the php code with something more suitable to a linux environment. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome!  You've probably thought of this already, but if this is on a public IP address, remember to firewall your port so strangers don't trigger your script.